# why hadoop input and output directory are not visible?

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop. I just installed it and started working on it.

Every  thing is running correctly but i am unable to find **input** and **output** directory in my laptop which is created by following command.

```
  hadoop fs -mkdir /home/hadoop/input
```

and

```
  hadoop fs -mkdir /home/hadoop/output
```

i want to mention again that i am able to perform operation on these **input** and **output** direcories, but these directory are not shown by 
following command

```
  $ ls /home/hadoop
```

please answer why directory are invisible to me.
Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /home/hadoop/input
```

makes that directory on the distributed file system, not your local machine.  To see that directory go to http://{namenodeIPAddr}:50070 in firefox/chrome/IE/whatever and click the Browse link.  Also, similar to how you created the folder using the above command, you can view them by running the following from the command line.

```
hadoop fs -ls /home/hadoop
```

Comment: please suggest in little bit detail that how to see directory. I am unable to understand which browser link are you talking about. I am new to  hadoop.

Comment: You will be having a web app which gives you details of namenode and datanode. The default port is 50070. So if namenode is up and running, you should see this [link](http://localhost:50070) working in you system. There you can go to Browse link and see the new folder created. As @JHowIX said, you can use `hadoop fs -ls /home/hadoop` command also to see the folder created from the shell

Comment: @SUSHANTSRIVASTAVA - I made some edits to my answer, please let me know if that clears it up